# Can I say, "He goes on to say" in an academic paper?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions

I have already used, "He states/asserts/postulates" in my paper quite a bit and I don't want to repeat myself again. I want to add another quote by the same author, but I'm not sure if this is acceptable: "He goes on to say, '......' ". Is this okay for an academic paper? What are some other common academic phrases we could use for "He said" and "He also said"?

Comment: "Johnson continues, 'blah blah blah'."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possible choices:

> - Johnson [thanks, Hotlicks] has been quoted as saying, "Yadda, yadda, yadda . . .."
> - According to Johnson, "Yadda . . .."
> - In the opinion of Johnson, "Yadda . . .."
> - From Johnson's perspective in his seminal work *Yadda Yadda*, "Yadda . . .."
> - Furthermore, from Johnson's perspective, "Yadda . . .."
> - Johnson's comments regarding _____________ are quite perceptive: "Yadda . . .."
> - Johnson delivered the *coup de grâce* to Smith's theory with this observation:  "Yadda . . .."
> - In Johnson's typically doctrinaire style, "Yadda . . .."
> - Lending a note of credibility to his argument, Johnson insists that "Yadda . . .."
> - On balance, Johnson is correct when he observed that "Yadda . . .."
> - Johnson sides with the conservative faction, as is evident in the following quotation:  "Yadda . . .."
> - Johnson evidently hews to the current paradigm when he says, "Yadda . . .."
> - The following quotation from Johnson's magnum opus *Yadda Yadda* serves to illustrate how behind the times he is regarding _______________: "Yadda, yadda, yadda . . .."

I could go on at length; I won't. This short list can serve, perhaps, as a springboard for coming up with your own ways of introducing a quotation. By the way, "He goes on to say" sounds fine to me.

Comment: @PatterEnglish: You're welcome! Best wishes to you. Don

Answer (score 1):

You may also be creative and use ellipses to combine ideas.
**In consideration of Senator Boyd's proposal, Judge Thomas explained, "The senator brings several poignant and provocative ideas to the court ... [however,] they are not supported by his data."**